# Hiding the Cursor / Warp Mouse (SDL 1.3)

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse, sdl, ubuntu-10.10

I've been unable to hide the mouse cursor (properly) using SDL. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and have been using the following:

```
SDL_ShowCursor( SDL_DISABLE ); 
SDL_WarpMouse( x, y );
```

Neither of which function properly at all; it would appear to have no visual effect, there is however a triggered mouse motion event as the documentation states, but the mouse does not move in any or disappear on screen.

The SDL Window is created (via SDL_CreateWindow) with the flags SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN. Fullscreen has no effect on the outcome.

Running the window at low resolutions in fullscreen mode (such as 640x480), does provide the desired effect of the commands; but the cursor bleeds through from the underlying windows. 
Around 1024x768, it has a completely different cursor icon.
As I get higher in resolution, it stops bleeding through and just acts as though its a window (the Gnome cursor). With no effect of above commands.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you mean SDL_OPENGL. I don't think you need whatever SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN is. As for your warp code, it matches mine exactly. I'm not exactly sure what could be wrong.

Comment: I think I should note I'm using SDL 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, cursors are not yet implemented in SDL 1.3.  I'm sort of intentionally leaving them unimplemented as a reminder that 1.3 isn't ready yet. *

[Quote by Sam Lantinga, an SDL Developer](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=6974); therefore this question is simply an SDL bug (soon to be fixed).

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but it's still actual.

Here's the solution:

Where you want to hide the cursor, write this:

```
SDL_Cursor *cursor; /* Make this variable visible in the point
                       where you exit the program */
int32_t cursorData[2] = {0, 0};
cursor = SDL_CreateCursor((Uint8 *)cursorData, (Uint8 *)cursorData, 8, 8, 4, 4);
SDL_SetCursor(cursor);
```

Where you exit the program:

```
SDL_FreeCursor(cursor);
```